# How to detect if entity has no attribute (not model) in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I ran this query:

```
  restaurantTable = RestaurantTable.all().filter('restaurant', restaurantKey)
    .filter('prepaymentPerReservable', None)
    .get()
```

It give no results since all RestaurantTable have no prepaymentPerReservable (freshly added to db.Model).

I also ran this query on same data:

```
  restaurantTables = RestaurantTable.all().filter('restaurant', restaurantKey)
  hasField = [x.key().id() for x in restaurantTables if x.prepaymentPerReservable == None]
```

It gives 4 results (4 entities have no prepaymentPerReservable) and x.prepaymentPerReservable == None is valid.

The question is how do I detect that an entity has no field or field has None value if x.prepaymentPerReservable == None is always true for both case?

Comment: Maybe I unnderstand your question. You cannot filter on a property in an entity, which have never been set. But if you get all the entities and iterate, you can check every for the attribute. It is an object, so: hasattr(entity, property_name).

Comment: I am asked how to detect that entity does not have field - hasattr(entity, property_name) is wrong since no difference it always None if you set or not - it explained in question!?